# kusto query from applicationinsights trace logs returns empty fields

Tags: json, azure-application-insights, azure-queues, kql

I am really struggling with this actually. I have a Kusto Query which until yesterday worked well...nothing ahs changed since then.

I need to query applicationinsights trace logs to get particular data.

First look at the following data and query which worked until yesterday

[Data to be queried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQH2k.png)

If I want to query a particular field which obviously contains data (see above screenshot) I get an empty result.

[Query with empty fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmdMD.png)

This worked yesterday and today I get this result.

Did anybody experience similar behaviour?

Any hints are highly appreciated.

Comment: could you check if the bottom note on this doc (applying `parse_json()` more than once, after invoking `tostring()`) solves it? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/parsejsonfunction

Comment: thx for the hint, will check :)